# Android Spliting the string to array

Tags: java, android, string

I want to split an android string to smaller ones with any `|` char.

Just imagine I have this long string :

```
This|is|a|long|string|in|java
```

So, I wanna split it. I need to get a array in output with this values :

```
[1]=>"This"
[2]=>"is"
[3]=>"a"
[4]=>"long"
[5]=>"string"
[6]=>"in"
[7]=>"java"
```

I have tried :

```
separated = oldstring.split("|");
```

But, i didn't give me the thing i need!

How can i do that? Any code can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021074/string-delimiter-in-string-split-method

Comment: @FrankN.Stein hey this is EXACTLY what i have tried!

Comment: @SureshAtta has the perfect answer for you.

Comment: Using String Tokenizer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that [`String's split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method take regex as a param. Not string.

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Since `|` is a meta character, and it's have a special meaning in regex.

It works when you escape that.

```
String separated[]  = oldstring.split("\\|");
```

Comment: oh that's worked, Thanks alot.

Comment: If worked then accept please