# How to split twice and take final value using Java

Tags: java, split

I have a string output like,

```
output=  [http://my1/new/Info_one, http://my1/new/Info_two, http://my1/new/Info_three]
```

I need to take only  `[Info_one,Info_two,Info_three]`. I tried using,

```
    -----
    -----
    System.out.println("output="+output);  // above result
    String[] output2= output.split(",");   
    System.out.println("output2="+output2);  // result is like----->[Ljava.lang.String;@7013d1
    String[] output3= output2.split("/")   //gave error----->Cannot invoke split(String) on the array type String[]
```

How I can take only last part of this outputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String delimiter in string.split method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021074/string-delimiter-in-string-split-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have to split on each String in the array try

```
System.out.println("output="+output);  
String[] output2= output.split(",");   

for (String member : output2) {
    String[] output3= member.split("/");

    for (String str : output3) {
      System.out.println (str);
    }

    // or just the last one

    System.out.println (output3[output3.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I first tried using `member.split(",");` . It display an error  on `output2`  like `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable`.

Comment: I have edited my code - hopefully to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you again. It gave result `output2=[Ljava.lang.String;@a7e1b1` and `output3=[Ljava.lang.String;@1db2007`

Comment: I have completed the puzzle for you in my edited answer,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It help to separate values. if I want to take only last value like `[Info_one,Info_two,Info_three]`, how to change it?

Comment: Is this what you want?