# I want to separate several parts of a String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to get two integer values separated form a string `XmodX` one is before mod and other is after mod the integers can be of any length. what is the best way to to so?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String delimiter in string.split method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021074/string-delimiter-in-string-split-method)

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: **split** on `mod` and then parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach should work...

```
// The variable 'parts' will contain 2 items:  your 2 integers, though they will still be String objects
String[] parts = myString.split("mod");

try {
    int firstInt = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int secondInt = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
) catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // One of your Strings was not an integer value
}
```